# How to solve Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when setting lower_case_table_names=0?

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, settings

When creating tables in mysql i noticed that all my table names started with lowercase even when I namned them with an upper case.

I found that going into :

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

Opening the my.ini file and changing the `lower_case_table_names=0`

Would to the trick according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rd79CYQTvFE).

After doing the above I shutdown the server, restarted the pc
and when trying to start the server again Im getting the following error:

> Could not connect, server may not be running. Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on 'localhost' (10061)

When I change back `lower_case_table_names=1`

It works again. How do I solve this?

EDIT:

Instead of going into the ini file I found I could change the property through the

> Options file

Then under general tab I found `lower_case_table_names` and changed it to 0

But yet again same error.

Comment: Possibly both of the first Answers are relevant -- OS differences in handling file names led to the pre-8.0 need for the flag.  8.0 added to the issue by storing table names in an internal InnoDB database (the new "data dictionary").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89035

Since 8.0.5

> It is now prohibited to start the server with a lower_case_table_names
>   setting that is different from the setting used when the server was
>   initialized. The restriction is necessary because collations used by
>   various data dictionary table fields are based on the setting defined when
>   the server is initialized, and restarting the server with a different
>   setting would introduce inconsistencies with respect to how identifiers
>   are ordered and compared.

It is prohibited to do so and results that the service  won't start.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use value `2` for this configuration, since you are trying to use `0` on windows machine this might cause an issue in your database tables, based on the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) for windows/Mac OS usage for value `0`:

> Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
>   specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name
>   comparisons are case sensitive. **You should not set this variable to 0
>   if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file
>   names (such as Windows or macOS). If you force this variable to 0 with
>   --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption**
>   may result.

in the linked documentation value `2` would do the trick for your case, it will store the tables on the disk with the same names you used, lookup in this case will not be case sensitive:

> Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
>   specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL
>   converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case
>   sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not
>   case-sensitive! InnoDB table names and view names are stored in
>   lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1.